# click-propagate of a Ember-view

Tags: javascript, ember.js

i have a list of "modules" wich are represented using a custom view

```
App.ModuleBlockView = Ember.View.extend({
    tagName:            'div',
    draggable:          'true',
    attributeBindings:  ['style', 'draggable'],
    ...
```

This view is, as you can see, draggable to allow resorting.
In addition to the drag-functionality, a modal opens when the view gets clicked to provide detailed informations about the clicked-module.

Inside this view, i want to place a dropdown-menu as follow:

```
{{#view App.ModuleBlockView contentBinding="module"}}
    {{view Ember.Select
        contentBinding="module.whatever"
        ...}}
{{/view}}
```

but, if i click on the select-element the modal opens cause of the click-event which bubbles through the DOM.

What is the best way to prevent the click event from bubbling.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop event bubbling by returning false from the event handler. In your case it may be necessary to extend Ember.Select and override the click functionality.

```
click: function () {
    return false
}
```

If you add a [JSBin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/) demonstrating your problem to your question, then I will try to add this solution.